# Manipulate Api Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, algorithm, function

I have this data coming from an api, I am trying to fetch it on the UI using map method with React, it is been hard to do so since the object key is a date (Number).

```
const Data = [
  {
    20221011: "100.00",
    20221012: "100.00",
    20221013: "100.00",
    20221014: "100.00",
    20221015: "100.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "99.00",
    20221012: "99.00",
    20221013: "99.00",
    20221014: "99.00",
    20221015: "99.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "98.00",
    20221012: "98.00",
    20221013: "98.00",
    20221014: "98.00",
    20221015: "98.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "97.00",
    20221012: "97.00",
    20221013: "97.00",
    20221014: "97.00",
    20221015: "97.00",
  },
];
```

I am trying to manipulate this data and change it to something like below, so I can map over it easily.

I wanna have two properties, "key" for the date and "value" for the percentage.

If someone can help with an algorithm can solve this problem would be great.

thank you

```
  const Data = [
      {
      data: [
        {key: "10/11/2022", value: "100.00"},
        {key: "10/12/2022", value: "100.00"},
        {key: "10/13/2022", value: "100.00"},
        {key: "10/14/2022", value: "100.00"},
        {key: "10/15/2022", value: "100.00"},
        ] 
      },
      {
       data: [
       {key: "10/11/2022", value: "99.00"},
        {key: "10/12/2022", value: "99.00"},
        {key: "10/13/2022", value: "99.00"},
        {key: "10/14/2022", value: "99.00"},
        {key: "10/15/2022", value: "99.00"},
        ] 
      },
      {
       data: [
        {key: "10/11/2022", value: "98.00"},
        {key: "10/12/2022", value: "98.00"},
        {key: "10/13/2022", value: "98.00"},
        {key: "10/14/2022", value: "98.00"},
        {key: "10/15/2022", value: "98.00"},
        ] 
      },
      {
       data: [
        {key: "10/11/2022", value: "97.00"},
        {key: "10/12/2022", value: "97.00"},
        {key: "10/13/2022", value: "97.00"},
        {key: "10/14/2022", value: "97.00"},
        {key: "10/15/2022", value: "97.00"},
        ] 
      },
    ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at it. You can achieve the desired data via `map()`

```js
const Data = [{
    20221011: "100.00",
    20221012: "100.00",
    20221013: "100.00",
    20221014: "100.00",
    20221015: "100.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "99.00",
    20221012: "99.00",
    20221013: "99.00",
    20221014: "99.00",
    20221015: "99.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "98.00",
    20221012: "98.00",
    20221013: "98.00",
    20221014: "98.00",
    20221015: "98.00",
  },
  {
    20221011: "97.00",
    20221012: "97.00",
    20221013: "97.00",
    20221014: "97.00",
    20221015: "97.00",
  },
];

const result = Data.map(f => {
  return {
    data: Object.keys(f).map(m => {
      return {
        key: `${m.slice(4, 6)}/${m.slice(6, 8)}/${m.slice(0, 4)}`,
        value: f[m]
      }
    })
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks a lot, one more question, can you help with formatting the date. like 10/11/2022

Comment: Is it a constant format? Always like YYYYddMM?

Comment: yeah, it is like that from the backend, so I am trying to change it in the frontend.
 like mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Ok. I updated my answer please take a look @Rio

Comment: @Rio If one of the answers is correct, could you mark it as an answer?

Comment: Thank you @Batuhan so much, I took your answer an applied it to my logic and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Data = [
  {
    20221011: "100.00",
    20221012: "100.00",
    20221013: "100.00",
    20221014: "100.00",
    20221015: "100.00"
  },
  {
    20221011: "99.00",
    20221012: "99.00",
    20221013: "99.00",
    20221014: "99.00",
    20221015: "99.00"
  },
  {
    20221011: "98.00",
    20221012: "98.00",
    20221013: "98.00",
    20221014: "98.00",
    20221015: "98.00"
  },
  {
    20221011: "97.00",
    20221012: "97.00",
    20221013: "97.00",
    20221014: "97.00",
    20221015: "97.00"
  }
];

const arr = [];

  const parseDate = (param) => {
    const date = new Date(Number(param));
    return date.toLocaleDateString();
  };

  const data = Data.map((elem, i) => {
    arr.push({
      key: parseDate(Object.keys(elem)[i]),
      value: Object.values(elem)[i]
    });
    return { data: arr };
  });
  
  console.log(data)
```

Comment: thank you for the help, this is also a great way to solve the problem

Comment: @Mario Your date parsing working incorrectly. Keys are not  timestamp. Careful when parsing them ;)